# In Magento 2, how to create promo rule for buy one get one in backend for specific custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I am trying to create promo `cart rule` in magento 2 backend for a `specific attribute product` in cart for `buy 1 and get 1` with reference of default promo `buy 3 get 4th free`.

but It is not working as expected.

Can someone tell me how we can achieve this and what should be the condition/action exactly to be set for this rule?

when I check for two qty of my same product for which attribute is set in promotion rule, it is showing discount for 1 product which is fine. 
when I add one other product in cart it is still fine.
But when I add two qty of other product, for which attribute is not set, 
then also it is applying rule to that product and discount is getting added
in the cart, which should not be the case.

This is quite weird. Can someone check and let me know, what I am missing here?

Comment: Do you try to find answer in  http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Magento_Community_Edition_2.0_User_Guide.pdf?

Comment: Not exactly that, but same way I have applied rules,
In Condition Tab:
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true:
        Productcode  contains  6009515576134  
In Action Tab:

Apply: Buy X get Y
Discount Amount: 1
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To : 2
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) : 1

Don't know what I am missing. It is applying rule in all products and not working as expected.

Comment: The M1 link may help to configure same in M2 http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-create-coupon-codes-in-magento-beginners-tutorial-1/

Comment: My Bad, The other products in the cart were not having custom values set so they were getting included in condition. After setting values, working fine.
Any Idea how to implement this, if custom attr values are not set(multiselect) then they should not get included in condition?

Comment: edited my question. Issue still there. Can someone please respond?